# Drawing with functions on JFrame or JPanel java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, draw, paint

I wanted to know if it is possible to use/make a function in another Class to draw an image/oval and then call it in the paint public void in our main Class.

If I have

```
public class Trydraw{
    
    public void drawrcircle(Graphics g){  

        g.setColor(Color.RED);      
        g.drawOval(0, 0, 20,20);  
        g.fillOval(0,0,20,20);    

    } 
    
}
```

And then call it here this way

```
import java.awt.GridLayout; 
import javax.swing.*;
import  java.awt.*;

public class Display extends JPanel{
   public static void main(String[]haha){
        
       JFrame frame = new JFrame();  
       frame.setSize(800, 500);  
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
       frame.setVisible(true);  

   }

   public void paint(Graphics g){

       super.paint(g); 
       Trydraw l = new Trydraw();
       l.drawrcircle(g);

   }
}
```

Thanks for your future help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, if I get your question correctly.
Your sample code works for me if I add

```
frame.add(new Display());
```

to the end of your

```
public static void main(String[] haha)
```

method.

With your snippet the `paint(g)` method will never be called, because it will be executed with the initialization of the `JPanel` which will be initialized with the initialization the `Display` class (because of inheritance).

You probably want to create an instance of `Display`, which automatically initializes the `JPanel` with the overridden `paint(g)` method, thus the `new` Operator.
As the constructor of a `JPanel` returns a `JPanel`, the constructor of Display returns a type of `JPanel` as well, which contains the red circle. This `JPanel` needs to be added with the `add` method to your original `JFrame`.